# Testing the Success of a Congestion Algorithm

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, performance

How do you test whether a particular congestion algorithm is working for you? I ask because it's not as if I can easily re-create a representative workload for most algorithms.

I'm current looking at two things, but I'm open to more suggestions:

- The "segments retransmitted" from the output of `netstat -s`

My current thinking is that congestion could result in dropped packets some percentage of the time so while there may not be a 1:1 relationship between a packet being dropped and the server being notified of a congestion event, there may be a loose correlation to be drawn if switching to one algorithm resulted in fewer dropped packets.

Does this figure show segments that were retransmitted due to congestion or is it limited to lossy links? If so (and I'm thinking it might be the case) that might muddy the waters even more to the point of this not being a good metric to use.

- Is there a metric available to measuring the average age for TCP connections?

My thinking here is that TCP connections that finish earlier (absent a spike in errors and dropped packets) might indicate that data is being pushed through with less delay.

Comment: TCP connections finishing earlier indicates higher throughput, not lower latency. Ideally, you could get latency and/or throughput figures from your TCP-using applications (some games may show latency figures, http/ftp downloads show throughput,...)

Comment: Is there some scenario where increased throughput per-connection doesn't correspond with decreased latency? (really asking)

Comment: Increased througput for a connection can mean increased latency for the rest of the connections.

Comment: Yeah but wouldn't that tend to balance out if I'm looking at average figures?

Comment: I'm not sure. I think a long running non-fair high-throughput connection could increase the latency of short-lived connections, while not needing to recover from "lending" bandwidth to those other connections.

Comment: I'm thinking it would more or less. Establishing upper and lower bounds (rather than only looking at average throughput) is still a good idea. That was a good call on checking application metrics for confirmation. That sounds like it's pretty much the answer. Gets it closer to the workload than system-wide metrics would as well. Can you post something like that as an answer so I can accept it? If you could illustrate the concept to other by showing that the sixth column in Apache CLF log format is "time to complete" in seconds it would probably be helpful to others.

Comment: Right now, you can probably write a better answer than me, since you know better which application metrics you can access (that's why I said ideally, since I don't expect all TCP applications to expose relevant metrics).

Comment: Yeah but I don't want to take credit for what's basically your answer. Not to mention answers are supposed to be generic enough to answer other people's questions. So what I'm specifically doing doesn't matter for an answer on SE. I'll do it if you want, I just don't want to steal your imaginary internet points.

Comment: I have enough imaginary Internet points (see my stackoverflow account), I'm not sure of what exactly you want to test there, and it's Friday, so I don't trust my ability to write more than two consecutive coherent sentences.

Comment: Posted a longish answer, feel free to edit with anything you can see I missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Concise Version:**

As @ninjalj pointed out, the workload application should probably be considered the authoritative source on whether any given adjustment was beneficial to workload performance. Depending on whether your requirements are latency or only overall throughput on the system, you can make the judgment call as to whether changes in behavior better meet your performance requirements.

In this case, it would be making the change and noticing whether `httpd`'s overall latency went down.

---

**Longer Version With Specific Examples:**

To elaborate, I'll put this in context. Let's look at Apache `httpd`. You can log the time to complete a request in microseconds and the size of each request using the `LogFormat` and `CustomLog` directives. For instance:

```
LogFormat "%h %m %D %b" perflog
CustomLog /var/log/httpd/performance.log perflog
```

Which produces output similar to this:

```
xxx.xxx.28.20 GET 41140 86
xxx.xxx.28.20 GET 34468 28
xxx.xxx.28.20 GET 47612 1434
xxx.xxx.28.20 GET 54860 868
xxx.xxx.28.20 POST 97055 6283
xxx.xxx.28.20 GET 33754 53
xxx.xxx.28.20 GET 68964 8416
xxx.xxx.28.20 GET 1143827 11528
xxx.xxx.28.20 GET 38055 61
xxx.xxx.64.208 HEAD 6255 -
xxx.xxx.28.20 GET 36922 142
xxx.xxx.28.20 GET 51871 5581
```

I'm going to just concern myself with `GET` requests for this:

```
root@xxxxxxvlp14 /tmp $ grep GET /var/log/httpd/performance.log > work.log
root@xxxxxxvlp14 /tmp $ sed -i 's/-$/0/g' work.log
root@xxxxxvlp14 /tmp $
```

(for whatever reason `httpd` give you a hyphen instead of an integer 0).

We can then programatically pick it apart:

```
#!/bin/bash

totalRequests=$(cat /tmp/work.log | wc -l )

totalTime=$(awk 'BEGIN{ count=0 } {count = count + $3} END { print count }' /tmp/work.log)
averageTime=$( printf "%.2f" $(bc -l <<< "$totalTime / $totalRequests "))
minTime=$(sort -nk 3 work.log | head -1 | awk '{print $3}')
maxTime=$(sort -rnk 3 work.log | head -1 | awk '{print $3}')

totalBytes=$(awk 'BEGIN{ count=0 } {count = count + $4} END { print count }' /tmp/work.log)
minBytes=$(sort -nk 4 work.log | head -1 | awk '{print $4}')
maxBytes=$(sort -rnk 4 work.log | head -1 | awk '{print $4}')

echo "Total Requests In Sample: $totalRequests"

echo

echo "Total Time Taken: $totalTime ms (average: $averageTime ms)"
echo "Longest Request: $maxTime ms"
echo "Shortest Request: $minTime ms"

echo

echo "Total Data Moved: $totalBytes bytes"
echo "Largest Request: $maxBytes bytes"
echo "Smallest Request: $minBytes bytes"
```

Please no comments on the script, it's written for clarity, not efficiency. The above produces the following:

```
Total Requests In Sample: 207

Total Time Taken: 15138613 ms (average: 73133.40 ms)
Longest Request: 1143827 ms
Shortest Request: 1788 ms

Total Data Moved: 409825 bytes
Largest Request: 20476 bytes
Smallest Request: 0 bytes
```

Obviously, the above illustrates why it's important to get a lengthy sample. The numbers are correct though (the minute and a half long request was someone generating a report in Word format that included images/graphs, for the curious).

So you would coax apache into giving you a lengthy sample (probably over the course of a entire day) of normal activity, make your change, rotate the logs, then begin collecting logs again (e.g waiting through another 24 hour period).

Each service (NFS, other HTTP servers, Samba, FTP servers, etc) will have its own way of gathering information but generally there will be *some* means of recording time and throughput.

Answer (score 4):

> Does this figure show segments that were retransmitted due to congestion or is it limited to lossy links? If so (and I'm thinking it might be the case) that might muddy the waters even more to the point of this not being a good metric to use.

`segments retransmitted` in `netstat -s` includes all the kernel's TCP  retransmissions for any reason, including those listed in your question.   Those reasons could also include:

- Link errors
- Ethernet switch congestion
- Local host drops due to qos or resource depletion
- Remote host drops (perhaps due to some form of qos/resource depletion on the remote host)

Performance test engineers routinely deal with all these variables and ensure that they can measure them appropriately.   One of the first tests you should do is to ensure the cabling / network runs clean at the packet sizes and traffic rates in question.  This is normally done with a dedicated test appliance, such as those from Ixia or Spirent.

Once you baseline network performance,  you're in a position to run the test you're asking about.   Even if the network tested clean, you should still monitor switch  interface errors/drops during the host TCP test to ensure they don't skew your results.

As to your thoughts about creating congestion conditions, you may find it helpful to intentionally generate iperf UDP background traffic just below the qos class' queueing threshold before you run your TCP traffic.  If you find that you can't saturate the link you have, you also may find it helpful to negotiate the NIC down to 1GE or 100M.

All this may sound complicated,  and in some ways perhaps it is; however qos testing is entirely doable with proper focus and visibility to all the system components.